# Heat Equation with Singular Initial Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the 2D heat equation in cartesian coordinates with initial condition of the form $1/r$. The problem is as follows:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \right), & x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0 \\
u(x, y, 0) = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, & x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Separating variables doesn't seem to be the best approach here and I couldn't find the Fourier transform of this singular initial condition. So I'm trying to solve it via convolution:

$u(x, y, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(x - \xi, y - \eta, t) \frac{-\eta}{\xi^2 + \eta^2} \, d\xi \, d\eta$

where:
$G(x, y, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \alpha t} e^{-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{4 \alpha t}}$

The problem is that the integral for $u(x,y,t)$ doesn't seem to have an analytical solution. Is that really that case? Can this PDE only be solved numerically?

Edit: The Fourier Transform of the initial condition can be found explicitly with Mathematica:

```
initialFourierTransform = -((I ky (HeavisideTheta[-kx] + HeavisideTheta[kx]))/(kx^2 + ky^2))
```

However the evaluation of the inverse Fourier transform to find the solution is taking a lifetime and I suspect there might be an error.

```
uHat[kx_, ky_, t_] := 
 initialFourierTransform*Exp[-alpha*(kx^2 + ky^2)*t]

(*Compute the inverse Fourier transform to find u(x,y,t)*)
u[x_, y_, t_] := 
 InverseFourierTransform[uHat[kx, ky, t], {kx, ky}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Perhaps polar coordinates may be more fruitful?

Comment: Alternatively, the Fourier transform of a very similar function is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973394/fourier-transform-of-frac-x-x2y2

Comment: I can evaluate the Fourier transform explicitly on Mathematica, the result is `-((I ky (HeavisideTheta[-kx] + HeavisideTheta[kx]))/(kx^2 + ky^2))` however evaluating the inverse Fourier transform to find the solution is taking a lifetime and I suspect an error.